# How can I "interpolate" these names into a method / variable that I want to update?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my new game I have several different animals that I can add and remove from specific paddocks. The code is working as intended but it is very repetitive and long. Currently, I am using (multiple) switch statements to grab a string called itemName from scriptable objects that hold the animal info.

As you can see in my code below, its unsightly with lots of duplicated code! **Is there a suggested way to reduce and improve this given the chunks of code in each case are identical apart, from the animal name string?** I use multiple switch statements in the same type of way throughout my project and it would reduce hundreds of lines.

I am relatively new to programming. When looking through documentation, I thought string interpolation might be the way to do it but couldn't figure it out how to make it actually refer to the right variable (like an int in my save file).

Essentially, what I would want to do is take the `item.itemName`, remove any spaces and make all lowercase, and then "plug it in" where needed, like `saveMgr.myStats.{theNewItemName}-= 1;` or similar. Then I would need like 6 lines instead of like 300.

Here is my code. The content I left in is just to show how duplicated it is right now.

```
            switch (item.itemName)
            {
                case "Albino Goat":
                    saveMgr.myStats.albinogoat -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.albinogoat += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.albinogoat, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Arabian Horse":
                    saveMgr.myStats.arabianhorse -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.arabianhorse += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.arabianhorse, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Bull Calf":
                    saveMgr.myStats.bullcalf -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.bullcalf += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.bullcalf, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Cow Calf":
                    saveMgr.myStats.cowcalf -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.cowcalf += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.cowcalf, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Merino Lamb":
                    saveMgr.myStats.merinolamb -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.merinolamb += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.merinolamb, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Piglet":
                    saveMgr.myStats.piglet -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.piglet += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.piglet, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Quarter Horse":
                    saveMgr.myStats.quarterhorse -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.quarterhorse += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.quarterhorse, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Azteca Horse":
                    saveMgr.myStats.aztecahorse -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.aztecahorse += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.aztecahorse, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Bull":
                    saveMgr.myStats.bull -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.bull += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.bull, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Cow":
                    saveMgr.myStats.cow -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.cow += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.cow, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Grey Goat":
                    saveMgr.myStats.greygoat -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.greygoat += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.greygoat, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Merino Sheep":
                    saveMgr.myStats.merinosheep -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.merinosheep += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.merinosheep, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Pig":
                    saveMgr.myStats.pig -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.pig += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.pig, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Black Lamb":
                    saveMgr.myStats.blacklamb -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.blacklamb += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.blacklamb, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Black Sheep":
                    saveMgr.myStats.blacksheep -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.blacksheep += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.blacksheep, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Dark Horse":
                    saveMgr.myStats.darkhorse -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.darkhorse += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.darkhorse, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Dorper Sheep":
                    saveMgr.myStats.dorpersheep -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.dorpersheep += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.dorpersheep, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Dorper Lamb":
                    saveMgr.myStats.dorperlamb -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.dorperlamb += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.dorperlamb, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Berkshire Pig":
                    saveMgr.myStats.berkshirepig -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.berkshirepig += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.berkshirepig, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Berkshire Piglet":
                    saveMgr.myStats.berkshirepiglet -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.berkshirepiglet += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.berkshirepiglet, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Swiss Cow":
                    saveMgr.myStats.swisscow -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.swisscow += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.swisscow, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
                case "Swiss Cow Calf":
                    saveMgr.myStats.swisscowcalf -= 1;
                    specificPaddock.swisscowcalf += 1;
                    PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock.swisscow, specificPaddock, item);
                    UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
                    break;
            }
```

So yeah, the code works as intended but I am unhappy with the messiness and want to understand alternative ways to plan this logic, especially for planning my next game. Thank you for reading.

Comment: well where does `item.name` come from?

Comment: I have scriptable objects for my animals. Item is referring to a scriptable object. In the scriptable object, there is info like item name, description, sprite, etc.

Comment: In this case why don't you use also a simple `int` `item.inPaddock` and `item.inStats` or similar so it is automatically serialized along with the scriptableObject itself

Comment: I am not serializing my scriptable objects at the moment - they are pretty much only used to pull information from for a couple places like scrolling UI shops. Also, not sure if it matters but I have almost twenty paddocks, so would I need to do ```item.inPaddock1```,```item.inPaddock2```, etc and make them part of my scriptable object?

Comment: scriptableObjects are serialized anyway like everything else in the Inspector, scenes, prefabs etc. to provide a full solution we would need a full code example here

Comment: I meant saving not serializing, sorry. Beginner here. I think in this case, my logic in the entire project would need to be organized in a vastly different way in order to achieve what I wanted in the chunk of code above. Would prefer not to give a full code example as it is quite a lot of lines. I will take some learnings for next time.

Answer (score 3):

You can think animal is an object. Let's go into the OOP world.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        Item item = new Item("Albino Goat");
        SaveManager saveMgr = new SaveManager(new List<Animal>() { new Animal("Albino Goat") });
        Paddock specificPaddock = new Paddock();

        Animal animal = saveMgr.Remove(item.Name);
        specificPaddock.Add(animal);

        //UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
    }

    private class SaveManager
    {
        private List<Animal> animals = null;

        public SaveManager(List<Animal> animals)
        {
            this.animals = animals ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(animals));
        }

        public Animal Remove(string animalName)
        {
            Predicate<Animal> match = (x) => x.Name.Equals(animalName);
            if (animals.Exists(match))
            {
                return animals.Find(match);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    private struct Item
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public Item(string name)
        {
            Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        }
    }

    private class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public Animal(string name)
        {
            Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        }
    }

    private class Paddock
    {
        private List<Animal> animals = null;

        public Paddock()
        {
            animals = new List<Animal>();
        }

        public void Add(Animal animal)
        {
            animals.Add(animal);
            Debug.LogFormat("Animal count in Paddock : {0}", animals.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote every private class as temp.

Just take my thinking about relationship with each object from this code.

Don't need to save every animal as int.

Code will be working so just copy and paste and try to see what's going on in the editor.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply and effort in putting together a code example. I can see how this type of thinking and organizing would be beneficial for my issue. Unfortunately I can't just drop it in my current project to tell you whether or not it works as I have a lot of interlinked stuff going on with my current set up. I'll look at setting up like you have supplied - there are some new concepts to me in there so will try to learn and understand the code and also better understand OOP.

Comment: @MelissaK Thank you for you kind reply. I understand it'll be hard to adopt it. But it's worth to do it. And please don't forget to consider pick my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use a `Dictionary<string,int>`, then you could replace the whole switch statement with something like

```
saveMgr.myStats[item.itemName] -= 1;
specificPaddock[item.itemName] += 1;
PaddockAddEvent(item.itemName, specificPaddock[item.itemName], specificPaddock, item);
UpdateStatOnAnimalAddEvent(onePercent);
```

For further safety, also consider creating an enum AnimalType, and turning the dictionary into `<AnimalType,int>`, as well as look into the animal-as-class-object approach others suggest. You are on the right track by wanting to follow DRY, aka Don't Repeat Yourself -- Good luck!

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response and dictionary suggestion. I see how they could be really useful. I did consider dictionaries for my project but opted not to because I thought I'd have issues with serializing/deserializing my save data.

Comment: Note there's [custom serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization) if you ever run into issues with native options.